# Spring Boot Kafka start if broker not available

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a Spring boot application where I'm consuming from a Kafka topic. The problem is that if the broker is unavailable, the application will shutdown. I want to avoid this behaviour since it's expected that the app continues to work because it has other functionalities. How can I make sure that my service stays up even if the broker is unavailable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the listener container property `missingTopicsFatal` to `false` to prevent looking for the topics during start up.